# ASP.NET VB.NET - Page doesn't load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012, sqlconnection, datareader

Can anyone tell me why the page keeps loading (never loads) when I try to run this this code?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class Admin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnSearchUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchUser.Click

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim searchComm As String = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE @username"
        Dim user_id_select As New Integer

        Dim searchSQL As New SqlCommand

        conn.Open()

        searchSQL = New SqlCommand(searchComm, conn)
        searchSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserSearch.Text)

        Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = searchSQL.ExecuteReader()

        While datareader.Read

            lstUsers.Items.Add(datareader.Item("username"))

        End While

        datareader.Close()
        conn.Close()


        Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim selectComm As String = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=@username_selected"

        Dim selectSQL As New SqlCommand

        conn2.Open()


        selectSQL = New SqlCommand(selectComm, conn2)
        selectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username_selected", lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text.Trim)

        Dim datareader2 As SqlDataReader = selectSQL.ExecuteReader()

        While datareader2.Read

            If datareader2.HasRows Then

                user_id_select = datareader2("user_id")

                lblUserSelected.Text = "Selected: " + lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text

            ElseIf datareader2.HasRows = False Then

                lblInvalidUsername.Visible = True
                datareader2.Close()


            End If

        End While


        conn2.Close()



    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drpProjects.SelectedIndexChanged



        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim sqlComm As String = "SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE project_name=@projectname"
        Dim sqlProjname As New SqlCommand

        conn.Open()

        sqlProjname = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
        sqlProjname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectname", drpProjects.SelectedItem.Text)
        Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlProjname.ExecuteReader()
        datareader.Read()


        If datareader.HasRows Then

            lblProjName.Text = datareader("project_name").ToString()
        End If

        datareader.Close()
        conn.Close()

        lblProjName.Visible = True
        grdProjDetails.Visible = True







    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnManageProj_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnManageProj.Click

        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2)


    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnProjSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProjSettings.Click

        Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim sqlComm2 As String = "SELECT project_id FROM projects WHERE project_name=@projectname"
        Dim sqlProjID As New SqlCommand

        conn2.Open()

        sqlProjID = New SqlCommand(sqlComm2, conn2)
        sqlProjID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectname", drpProjects.SelectedItem.Text)
        Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlProjID.ExecuteReader()
        datareader.Read()


        If datareader.HasRows Then

            Dim UserID As String
            UserID = datareader("project_id").ToString

            Session("project_id") = UserID
            Response.Redirect("Project.aspx")

        End If

        datareader.Close()
        conn2.Close()



    End Sub
End Class
```

Admin.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p style="font-size: xx-large; text-decoration: underline">
    <strong>Manage User</strong>&nbsp;</p>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <p>
                <strong>Search User:</strong>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearchUser" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Text="Search" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstUsers" runat="server" Height="47px" Width="160px"></asp:ListBox>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblUserSelected" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="surname" HeaderText="surname" SortExpression="surname" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="occupation" HeaderText="occupation" SortExpression="occupation" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="department" HeaderText="department" SortExpression="department" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="work_location" HeaderText="work_location" SortExpression="work_location" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [surname], [occupation], [department], [work_location] FROM [users] WHERE ([user_id] = @user_id)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="user_id" SessionField="UserID" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInvalidUsername" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="Invalid Username selected." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnViewProfile" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Text="View Profile" />
            </p>
            <hr />
            <p style="font-size: xx-large; text-decoration: underline">
                <strong>Manage Projects</strong></p>

            <p style="font-size: xx-large; ">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCreateProj" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" Height="38px" Text="CREATE" Width="100px" />
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnManageProj" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" Height="38px" Text="MANAGE" Width="100px" />
            </p>

            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                   <strong> Create a new project</strong><br />
                    </asp:View>
                        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                        <strong>Manage an existing project</strong><br />
                            Select a project:<asp:DropDownList ID="drpProjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="project_name" DataValueField="project_name" AutoPostBack="True">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [project_name] FROM [projects]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProjName" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#006699"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:GridView ID="grdProjDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="project_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Visible="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="project_id">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("project_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("project_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="project_type">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_start" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="project_start">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_finish" HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="project_finish">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_duration" HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="project_duration">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_budget" HeaderText="Budget" SortExpression="project_budget">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="project_cost">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="project_manager_id" HeaderText="Project Manager #" SortExpression="project_manager_id">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="team_leader_id" HeaderText="Team Leader #" SortExpression="team_leader_id">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" BorderColor="#003366" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2px" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT [project_id], [project_type], [project_start], [project_finish], [project_duration], [project_budget], [project_cost], [project_manager_id], [team_leader_id] FROM [projects] WHERE ([project_name] = @project_name) ORDER BY [project_start]">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpProjects" Name="project_name" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnProjSettings" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Text="VIEW PROFILE" Width="113px" />
                        </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
            <br />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<p>

    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

MasterPage.aspx

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script runat="server">



    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If Session("userid") = Nothing Then
            txtLoginUser.Visible = True
            txtLoginPass.Visible = True

        Else


            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim useridComm As String = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE user_id=@userid"
            Dim sqlUserID As New SqlCommand

            conn.Open()

            Dim userid As String = Session("userid")

            sqlUserID = New SqlCommand(useridComm, conn)
            sqlUserID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
            Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlUserID.ExecuteReader()
            If datareader.HasRows Then

                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(datareader("user_id"), True)
                lblLoggedIn.Text = datareader("name").ToString() & " " & datareader("surname").ToString()

            End If
            datareader.Close()
            conn.Close()

        End If
    End Sub

   Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim loginSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim loginComm As String

        Dim CommonFunctions As New CommonFunctions()
        Dim dec_pass As String = CommonFunctions.EncryptPassword(txtLoginPass.Text.Trim)

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")


        loginComm = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=@username and password=@password"

        conn.Open()


        loginSQL = New SqlCommand(loginComm, conn)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtLoginUser.Text.ToString)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", dec_pass)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = loginSQL.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()


        If dr.HasRows Then
            Session("userid") = dr("user_id")
        ElseIf dr.HasRows = False Then

            lblRegister.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblRegister.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
        End If
        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub





</script>



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">
        <strong>Header:</strong> Mobile CMS

        </header>


<section id="login">

    <div id="login-form">

         <p>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="U:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginUser" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername0" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="P:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginPass" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" TextMode="Password" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" />

                </p>

                <p>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegister" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0000CC" Text="Register"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblLoggedIn" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                </p>
         <p>

                    &nbsp;</p>



    </div>

</section>

<div class="navigation-bar">
       <ul class="navigation-menu">

            <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="mainsettings">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="profile">Profile</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="settings">Profile Settings</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="uploads">Uploads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="documents">Media</a>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="docs">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="others">Others</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#" class="projects">Projects</a>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="yprojects">Your Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="otherprojects">Other Projects</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>


    <section id="middle">

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>



    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
        <strong>Footer:</strong> adsfdsgfds
    </footer>

</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using VB.NET/ASP.NET with SQL-Server-2012 on Win 7 Ultimate.

Is it maybe because I have more than one data reader?

Comment: Are you able to debug the page in Visual Studio (or the IDE of choice)?

Comment: Can you load an empty page? i.e. a page with no controls or logic in code-behind.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, I have loaded (successfully) another page.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing any code in Page_Load, so why should your page keep loading? Also, you have too many database calls (closing and opening connections) in your `Buttons_Click` and `Dropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged`

I suspect your `SelectedIndexChanged` event for your dropdown. This event is also called when page loads as item are added to the dropdown list. This triggers the event and could be connecting to the database every time the event is triggered for each item in the dropdown

Take the `SelectedIndexChanged` and try to load the page again

Comment: Yes. I mean remove the event from the dropdown try again